# Study Error: Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0.0) in the lowest function. It must be 0

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm getting tripped up by this error all the time. I've applied nz to all possible calculations that could have this as a result, forcing a 1 in case of an error, but it doesn't help. What am I missing please? Is there a more elegant /standard way in Pinescript to avoid these errors during the first x bars?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Pullback", overlay = true)


ema = nz(ta.ema(close, 21),1)

plotcolor = color.white
message = ""
wehavealow = false
var pullback1 = false
var pullback2 = false
var feshort = false
var seshort = false


downtrendstart = nz(ta.crossunder(high, ema),1)
downtrend = high < ema
uptrend = low > ema


var int count = na

if downtrend
    count := 0
else
    count += 1

downduration = nz(ta.barssince(downtrendstart),1)

lowerlow = low < nz(ta.lowest(low,downduration),1.0)
brokelower = low < low[1]
pullback = low > low[1]

if lowerlow
    pullback1 := false
    pullback2 := false
    feshort := false
    seshort := false

if downtrend and not lowerlow

    if pullback2 and brokelower
        seshort := true
        message := "2es"
 
    if pullback1 and feshort and pullback
        pullback2 := true
        message := "pb2"
   
    if pullback1 and brokelower
        feshort := true
        message := "1es"

    if pullback and not pullback2
        pullback1 := true
        message := "pb1"

//Plot
if downtrend
    plotcolor :=color.red
if uptrend
    plotcolor := color.green

plot(ema, color=plotcolor)

if downtrend
    downlabel = label.new(bar_index, low, message, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style=label.style_label_up)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just find a great bug in Pinescript.
If you only use : 
`calcul := ta.lowest(low,downduration)`
in your script, without utilising 'calcul' after, you will not have any error.
As soon as, after, you try to use this variable 'calcul' in your script, it throw an error, for example, I add (just to see the content of 'calcul'):

```
var affichage = table.new(position.top_center, 1,1,bgcolor=color.white)
table.cell(affichage, column=0, row=0, text=str.tostring(calcul))
```

And I get the error :

> Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0.0) in the 'lowest' function.
> It must be >0.

You should report it to tradingview by opening a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

When `downtrendstart` is `true`, then `ta.barssince(downtrendstart)` will be equal to 0.
As the error mentioned, `ta.lowest()` function can't get 0 as a length argument, so the script will have a runtime error.
You can check the value of `downtrendstart` before assigning it to the `length` parameter:

```
lowerlow = downduration > 0 ? low < ta.lowest(low,downduration) : true
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, much appreciated. Initially I didn't understand why nz(ta.barssince(downtrendstart),1) didn't return a 1, but now it's clear that ta.barssince(downtrendstart) does not return an error and therefore nz doesn't return 1. thanks for your explanation. In the end I just changed ta.lowest(low,downduration) to ta.lowest(low,downduration+1) since looking back further doesn't make a difference on the first bar of the downtrend.